# SBT|Scala|Cucumber - Unresolved Dependencies during installation

Tags: scala, sbt, cucumber

With **sbt 0.13.8** and **Scala 2.10.5**, which dependencies are required in build.sbt and plugins.sbt to install Cucumber ?

SBT does not resolve *info.cukes* dependencies below.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.10.5",
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.11" % "test",
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.10.5",
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.10.5",
  "info.cukes" % "cucumber-scala" % "1.1.6",
  "info.cukes" % "cucumber-core" % "1.1.6"
   )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a different build of cucumber-scala for each version of Scala. So, you have to mention the desired Scala version. You can provide it in the name of artifact, for example:

```
libraryDependencies += "info.cukes" % "cucumber-scala_2.12" % "1.2.4"
```

or you can use the SBT shortcut "%%" which will substitute the correct Scala version for you:

```
libraryDependencies += "info.cukes" %% "cucumber-scala" % "1.2.4"
```

Comment: You allright : with Scala 2.10.5 and this dependencie   "info.cukes" % "cucumber-scala_2.10" % "1.2.4", everything works. Thanks.